# crontab with wget - why is it running twice?

Tags: wget, cron

I've a php script which runs from webservice and insert to DB.

crontab -e

```
......other cron tasks above.......
...
..
..
# Run test script.php at 1610
10 16 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /home/username/my_cronjobs/logs/cron_adhoc http://localhost/project/script.php
```

Apparently, at 16:10, this script is run twice!
16:10:01 and 16:25:02

Is it something wrong and gotta do with using wget?? 
Or did i set the schedule on cron job wrongly?

When i run http://localhost/project/script.php from browser, it will only run once..

Any idea regarding this problem ?

I've tested, there are no other users running the same job... I suspect the way wget works.

As my script needs at least 20mins to complete without sending back a response (it is pulling alot of data from webservicces and save to db) .. suspect there's a time out or retry of wget by default causing this problem.

Comment: The obvious question, have you tried running on the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think i solve my own question.

My php takes some time to load, i guess wget retries or time out after some default specified time.

I solved it by using /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 15):

[The wget docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) give a default read-timeout of 900 seconds, or 15 minutes.

> if, at any point in the download, no data is received for more than
>   the specified number of seconds, reading fails and the download is
>   restarted

This is why you were seeing the file called again 15 minutes later. You can specify a longer read-timeout by adding the parameter and an appropriate number of seconds:

```
--read-timeout=1800
```

Answer (score 1):

Whose user's crontab is this?

Check if there is another user for which you set up cron job at different time and forgot about it.

Comment: i only set up one, and no other users set up this job using wget

Comment: is it possible the wget is executing twice, does using -mirror help?

Comment: and here's the answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users