# when are cron.d jobs executed?

Tags: cron, debian

This is probably stupidly obvious beginner question, but somehow I can't find the answer.

On my debian box, I have a script in /etc/cron.d. It executes every once in a while, but I can't find the schedule or initiator. I've tried looking at all users cron tabs, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users), but no user has a script that runs the cron.d. I've looked at /etc/crontab, which holds the scripts for cron.daily, monthly and hourly, but not cron.d.

Where is this schedule held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of `man cron`,

> Support for /etc/cron.d is included in the cron  daemon  itself, 
>   which handles this location as the system-wide crontab spool.  This
>   directory can contain any file  defining  tasks  following  the 
>   format  used  in /etc/crontab, i.e. unlike the user cron spool, these
>   files must provide the username to run the task as in the task
>   definition.

This implies that the file inside `/etc/cron.d` should not be a script, but rather a configuration file that looks similar to `/etc/crontab`. It will carry its own scheduling information, the same way that `/etc/crontab` does. In particular, the format should look like:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

Comment: The script I was talking about, had a different markup than usual, so that was why I was confused. It started with `@daily` instead of the format you describe, and i'm (sort of) familiar with.