# Is there Any File that contain Cronjob list?

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a file read access on a website;

Is there any file (*not folder for directory list*) based on linux system that has cronjob list on it ?

I searched and found `/etc/crontab` but there is not any command here.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
```

For details see `man 5 crontab`

```
Example of job definition:
.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

Is there any alternative for cronjob commands file ?

(or maybe `/etc/crontab` is not the correct file?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list all cron jobs for all users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users)

Comment: Given that you tagged 'cpanel', this link is also interesting: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=885195

Comment: thanks i'll check it Niels Keurentjes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your crontab is (probably) stored in a file -- but there's no good reason to care about that.

On my system, that file is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/kst`, where `kst` is my user name. Yours may be different depending on your system (and of course your user name).

I got this information from the `crontab(1)` man page (`man crontab`, in the **`FILES`** section).

That file is not readable other than by the `root` user and if you're doing something that depends on the location of that file, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. On my system, the first line of that file is:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
```

You should use the `crontab` command to manage your crontab. It will let you *indirectly* edit the file, and it will manage the system so that it knows when it's been updated. If you manually modify it yourself, you'll probably just create a mess.

Use `crontab -l` to see your current crontab.

You can use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab (it invokes your default text editor). Personally, I avoid using `crontab -e`. Instead, I maintain a copy of my crontab in a separate file, managed by a source control system, and then use `crontab filename` to install it.

The `/etc/crontab` file is a *system* crontab, which uses a different syntax; it has a 6th field on each line specifying the user account to use to execute the command. (For a personal crontab, that's not necessary, since the command will be executed by the owner of the crontab.) There are typically a number of system crontab files; if you're curious, look in the following files and directories (these may or may not exist on your system):

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.hourly/*`
- `/etc/cron.daily/*`
- `/etc/cron.weekly/*`
- `/etc/cron.monthly/*`
- `/etc/cron.d/*`

Comment: crontab -l is my best answer but unfortunately i just have file read access and i cant execute this command . thanks for your help