# cron process was killed, yet process still seems to be running?

Tags: macos, cron, kill

I wrote a crontab that used to edit a file called `some_file.txt` every minute. So, every minute it used to keep getting renewed in my home directory.  I would verify this by doing `ls -alts` every minute, and the time stamp would always be the current minute.

I want to stop the cronjob, so I did the following:

1) deleted the cronjob file

The process kept running, and the file kept updating everyminute.

2) did `ps -A | egrep ".*cron.*"` to find the cron job process.  Killed the process with `sudo kill <PID>`.  However, it still runs!

3)  I also tried searching for the cron job by listing all existing cron jobs for all users, as shown [here in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users).  Still no luck!

how do I get rid  of the procecss?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find process by running

```
sudo ps aux
```

Execute `sudo kill -9 <PID>`
Restart cron`

When you run `sudo kill <PID>` the process get signal TERM. This signal could be intercepted by process. But when you execute `sudo kill -9 <PID>` the process get signal KILL and this signal could not be intercepted.
You can find more info about  signals here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -r` works.

I did not get a chance to try @zhigaev 's answer, but thank you.