# crontab script centos runs daily but also an extra one

Tags: linux, cron, centos

CentOS release 6.7

Vanilla install, all I have really done is added to /etc/crontab
59 23 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily

inside /etc/cron.daily is svn.sh which has a single line
/home/svn.sh 2>&1| mail -s "blah" myemailaddy

The final script dumps the database and does a svn commit on the zipfile.

The bizarre thing is that it emails me at 5 minutes past midnight showing the database dump output and the svn commit.  Then 4 hours later it runs again for no reason I can understand.  Does it every day but what time later can vary (e.g. might be 3.5 hours later)

There is just a single instance of crond running.

What can I look for to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is it possible that another user also has the same job scheduled? Here is a discussion on listing jobs across all users http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Comment: I took a look, no other crontab and its just a brand new system, nobody logs on except me - just runs one website.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it appears to be the run-parts /etc/cron.daily

not sure how that works, but not well.  Replacing that with calling the script directly and it works fine.