# How to find a specific cron job?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

My question is how to find a specific cron job?

I have a cron job that runs daily on my web/email server and I'm sure it exists, because I get an email every day about it. It's a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate renewal. Now I want to modify it, but I can't find it anywhere.

(Edit: moved "things I've tried" from here into the answer)

Comment: Did you search in `/var/spool/cron/` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's not there.

Comment: Maybe check your logs, find the line with your specific cron

Comment: What's your operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Does your web/email server has got any services deployed in containers?
Check the output of 'docker ps' and see if there are any running related web/email services. Connect to those instances and find the cron entries if any.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't have containers.

Comment: Check the list of processes and see if there are any zombie processes  with 'ps aux |grep defunct'

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are either user specific or system wide. You can list user specific cron jobs for all users by running the following command as root:

`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134944/4490400))

If it's not found, it's probably a system wide cron job and it's located in one of the following folders:

```
etc/crontab 
etc/cron.d
etc/cron.daily
etc/cron.hourly
etc/cron.monthly
etc/cron.weekly
```

Try running: `grep -rnw '/etc/' -e 'keyword'`

This command lists you all the files inside `/etc/` which contain the keyword you are looking for, so it might also list you unrelated files.

In my case, the LetsEncrypt certificate renewal job turned out to be in `etc/crontab`, which I thought I had checked already with `crontab -e`, but it turns out they are different: `crontab -e` is for user specific cron jobs, while `etc/crontab` is for system wide cronjobs. This is also the reason why this cron job didn't appear when I was listing all cron jobs for all users.