# change letsencrypt certbot run time

Tags: cron, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have setup certbot for letsencrypt key renewal. This works.

When i check my logs at /etc/log/letsencrypt i see it runs twice a day.
Somewhere around midnight and somewhere around noon.

I would like to run it only once a day somewhere in the early morning.

To get control over the running of certbot i removed all entries from my cronjobs. But unexpectedly it still runs.

So how is certbot started?

Extra info:

when i run a script to show all cronjobs i get this:
(script: [How do I list all cron jobs for all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users) )

```
mi  h    d  m  w  user  command
0   3    *  *  1  root  /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
0   */4  *  *  *  root  /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
16  10   *  *  *  root  test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/apache2
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/aptitude
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/automysqlbackup
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/exim4-base
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/man-db
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/ntp
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/passwd
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest
25  6    *  *  *  root  /etc/cron.daily/tomcat8
30  2    1  *  *  root  /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
30  3    *  *  *  root  /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
47  6    *  *  7  root  /etc/cron.weekly/man-db
```

the file from certbot i found was certbot in /etc/cron.d

it contained this line:

```
#0 4 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

which i commented out (with the #).

my system is debian:

Debian GNU/Linux 9

Answer (score 1):

I use certbot with Ubuntu 16.04 + nginx
There are two places  to check  jobs related to Certbot

1) /etc/cron.d/certbot

here you have

`0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew && nginx -s reload`

2) systemd timer

run commnad:
$sudo systemctl list-timers

and see output

Sun 2018-07-08 00:46:59 EEST  7h left       Sat 2018-07-07 12:36:26 EEST  4h 51min ago certbot.timer                certbot.service

then

3)

go to  check file that control time when systemctl  run Certbot

/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/certbot.timer

that is symbolic link for

/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer

Pay attention to this lines that define  times + random seconds (set a random time for purpose to don't stress simultaneously letsencrypt servers)

OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00

RandomizedDelaySec=3600